# for-loop Python 3.5. Creating a quiz for students I tutor

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

Hello I'm currently trying to make a quiz application for year english students. I'm using Python 3.5. and I'm kinda new. The quizz is supposed to work like below I'll include the code as well.

> WELCOME TO YOUR QUIZ
>
> Word 1/5: Potato How many consanants does the word contain?
>
> 3
>
> Correct!
>
> Word 2/5: Potato How many vowels does the word contain?
>
> 1
>
> Correct!
>
> Word 3/5: Name How many vowels does the word contain
>
> 5
>
> Incorrect! Correct answer 4
>
> Word 4/5: YES How many letters does the word contain? 3 Correct!
>
> Word 5/5: Day
>
> What is letter 3 of the word?
>
> Y
>
> Correct!
>
> Game Over. Your Score is 4/5

```
print('WELCOME TO YOUR QUIZ')

# Import the random module to allow us to select the word list and questions at random.
import random
quizWords = ['WOMBAT', 'COMPUTER', 'BOOKS', 'DAY', 'NIGHT', 'HOUR', 'POTATO', 'HUGE', 'TINY', 'GOOD', 'BAD', 'YES', 'NO', 'HOUSE', 'QUESTION', 'BALLOON', 'CAT', 'DUCK', 'KOOKARBURRA', 'POSTER', 'TELEVISION', 'PRINCE', 'RHYTHM', 'SUDDENLY', 'SNOW', 'MAGNET', 'TOWEL', 'WALKING', 'SPEAKER', 'UNCHARACTERISTICALLY']
s = random.sample (quizWords, 5)
# loop through the list using enumerate 
for index,w in enumerate(s):
    print("Word {}/{}:{}".format(index+1,len(s),w))
```

I want to generate a random number between 1 and 4, and use it to choose which question is asked for each word.

If the random number is 1, I want to ask the user “How many letters does the word contain?” and prompt them for input. Assess their answer, and then print an appropriate message. How would i fit that in?

Comment: On this site, show your appreciation by upvoting all the useful answers. You do that by clicking the up-arrow at the top-left of the answer. In addition accept the best answer by clicking the checkmark near the top-left of the answer. That is better than saying thanks in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would go about creating a quiz. Obviously you can update the print statements to follow your own desired format. Hope that this helps!

```
import random
import string

def consonant_count(word):
    word = word.lower()
    return len([x for x in word if x in consonants])

def vowel_count(word):
    word = word.lower()
    return len([x for x in word if x in vowels])

def prompt_letter_count(word):
    correct = word_map[word]['letters']
    ans = input('How many letters does "{}" contain?'.format(word))
    return check(ans, correct)

def prompt_vowel_count(word):
    correct = word_map[word]['vowels']
    ans = input('How many vowels does "{}" contain?'.format(word))
    return check(ans, correct)

def prompt_consonant_count(word):
    correct = word_map[word]['consonants']
    ans = input('How many consonants does "{}" contain?'.format(word))
    return check(ans, correct)

def prompt_random_letter(word):
    n = random.randint(0, len(word))
    correct = word[n-1]
    ans = raw_input('What is letter {} of "{}"?'.format(n, word))
    return check(ans.lower(), correct.lower())

def check(ans, correct):
    if ans == correct:
        return prompt_correct()
    return prompt_incorrect()


def prompt_correct():
    print('That is correct! :)')
    return 1

def prompt_incorrect():
    print('That is incorrect :(')
    return 0

def next_question(word):
    q_type = input_map[random.randint(1, 4)]
    return q_type(word)

vowels = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']
consonants = [x for x in string.ascii_lowercase if x not in vowels]
quizWords = ['WOMBAT', 'COMPUTER', 'BOOKS', 'DAY', 'NIGHT', 'HOUR', 'POTATO', 'HUGE', 'TINY', 'GOOD', 'BAD', 'YES', 'NO', 'HOUSE', 'QUESTION', 'BALLOON', 'CAT', 'DUCK', 'KOOKARBURRA', 'POSTER', 'TELEVISION', 'PRINCE', 'RHYTHM', 'SUDDENLY', 'SNOW', 'MAGNET', 'TOWEL', 'WALKING', 'SPEAKER', 'UNCHARACTERISTICALLY']
word_map = {x:{'consonants':consonant_count(x), 'vowels':vowel_count(x), 'letters':len(x)} for x in quizWords}
input_map = {1:prompt_letter_count, 2:prompt_vowel_count, 3:prompt_consonant_count, 4:prompt_random_letter}

def start_quiz(number_questions):
    current_question = 0
    correct_questions = 0
    if number_questions > len(quizWords):
        number_questions = len(quizWords)
    sample_questions = random.sample(quizWords, number_questions)
    print('WELCOME TO YOUR QUIZ')
    print '---------------------'
    for x in sample_questions:
        print 'Question {}/{}:'.format(current_question, number_questions)
        correct_questions += next_question(x)
        print '---------------------'
        current_question += 1
    print 'Congragulations on completing your quiz!'
    print "    Score {}/{}:".format(correct_questions, number_questions)
    try_again = raw_input('Would you like to try again? (y/n)').lower()
    if try_again == 'y' or try_again == 'yes':
        start_quiz(number_questions)

start_quiz(4)
```

Comment: is this python 3.5?

Comment: doesn't seem to want to run in 3.5

Answer (score 0):

I'm proposing a way to select a question, and associate a test function, which allows to define as many questions you want easily:

```
print('WELCOME TO YOUR QUIZ')

# Import the random module to allow us to select the word list and questions at random.
import random
quizWords = ['WOMBAT', 'COMPUTER', 'BOOKS', 'DAY', 'NIGHT', 'HOUR', 'POTATO', 'HUGE', 'TINY', 'GOOD', 'BAD', 'YES', 'NO', 'HOUSE', 'QUESTION', 'BALLOON', 'CAT', 'DUCK', 'KOOKARBURRA', 'POSTER', 'TELEVISION', 'PRINCE', 'RHYTHM', 'SUDDENLY', 'SNOW', 'MAGNET', 'TOWEL', 'WALKING', 'SPEAKER', 'UNCHARACTERISTICALLY']
s = random.sample (quizWords, 5)

def test_nb_vows(word):
    return sum(word.upper().count(x) for x in "AEIOUY")


qt = {"How many vowels does the word contain?" : test_nb_vows, "How many letters does the word contain?" : len}

# loop through the list using enumerate
for index,w in enumerate(s):
    print("Word {}/{}:{}".format(index+1,len(s),w))
    # check question
    qk = random.choice(list(qt.keys()))
    answer = int(input(qk))
    real_answer = qt[qk](w)
    if real_answer == answer:
        print("Correct!")
    else:
        print("Noooo it is {}".format(real_answer))
```

The idea is to choose the question at random using `random.choice`. The choice is a key to a dictionary, and the value is the test function, which must have 1 parameters: the word itself, and returns the correct answer (restricted to a number right now), which is tested against user input

That way you can define a lot of questions as long as you provide the relevant test function. You just have to enrich `qt` and code the test function (or use existing functions like I did by reusing `len`). Good luck.

Comment: Thanks I'll have look at how it goes on python thanks for the advice. Man this community is really great when you're first starting out.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution:

```
# Import the random module to allow us to select the word list and
# questions at random.
import random

quizWords = [
    'WOMBAT', 'COMPUTER', 'BOOKS', 'DAY', 'NIGHT', 'HOUR', 'POTATO', 'HUGE',
    'TINY', 'GOOD', 'BAD', 'YES', 'NO', 'HOUSE', 'QUESTION', 'BALLOON',
    'CAT', 'DUCK', 'KOOKARBURRA', 'POSTER', 'TELEVISION', 'PRINCE', 'RHYTHM',
    'SUDDENLY', 'SNOW', 'MAGNET', 'TOWEL', 'WALKING', 'SPEAKER',
    'UNCHARACTERISTICALLY'
]
s = random.sample(quizWords, 5)

def f0(word):
    """ TODO """
    return True

def f1(word):
    """ TODO """
    return True

def f2(word):
    """ TODO """
    return True

def f3(word):
    """ TODO """
    return True

def f4(word):
    """ TODO """
    return True

questions = {
    0: {
        "title": "How many consanants does the word {0} contain?",
        "f": f0
    },
    1: {
        "title": "How many vowels does the word {0} contain?",
        "f": f1
    },
    2: {
        "title": "How many vowels does the word {0} contain",
        "f": f2
    },
    3: {
        "title": "How many letters does the word {0} contain?",
        "f": f3
    },
    4: {
        "title": "What is letter 3 of the word {0}?",
        "f": f4
    }
}


# loop through the list using enumerate
for index, w in enumerate(s):
    print("Word {}/{}:{}".format(index + 1, len(s), w))
    type_question = random.randint(0, 4)
    print("{}".format(questions[type_question]["title"].format(w)))
    questions[type_question]["f"](w)
```

As you can see, you just use random.randint to pick up a random question from the questions dictionary. Now you just need to complete the logic of function f0..f4 ;-) . Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks I'll have look at in python. Massive help guys

Comment: @MikeLyn You're welcome, just one thing, the best way to thanks here in SO is validating or upvoting the answer you considered it was most helpful to you, those are the rules of the game ;)